# What is job.get() and job.getBoolean() in mapreduce

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I am working on pdf document clustering over hadoop so I am learning mapreduce by reading some examples on internet.In wordcount examples have lines

```
job.get("map.input.file")
job.getboolean()
```

What is function of these functions?what is exactly map.input.file where is it to set? or is it just a name given to input folder? 
Please post answer if anyone know.

For code see the following link 
wordcount 2.0 example=http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

These are job configurations. i.e. set of configurations which are passed on to each mapper and reducer. Now, these configurations consist of [well defined mapreduce/hadoop related configurations](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html) as well as user-defined configurations.

In your case, `map.input.file` is a pre-defined configuration and yes it is set to a comma separated list of all the paths you have set as input path.

While `wordcount.skip.patterns` is a custom configuration which is set as per user's input, and you may see this configuration to be set in `run()` as follows:

```
conf.setBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true);
```

As for when to use `get` and when to use `getBoolean`, it should be self-explanatory, as whenever you want to set a value of type boolean you will use `getBoolean` and `setBoolean` to get and set the specific config value respectively. Similarly you have specific methods for other data types as well. If it is string then you may use `get()`.